# My getters won't give an updated variable

Tags: java, getter-setter

I am trying to pass a variable to another class but my getter won't send the updated value of my variable it sends the value I used to initialize it.

Main class:

```
    OtherClass otherclass = new OtherClass(new Main());
    private boolean updateVar = true
    private int timer = 0;

    public void tick(){

        if(updateVar == true) timer++;
    }

    public int getTimer(){

        return timer;
    }
```

Other Class:

```
    Main main;
    private int holdTimer;

    public OtherClass(Main main){

       this.main = main;
       holdTimer = this.main.getTimer();

          System.out.println(holdTimer);
    }
```

Every time it comes out as 0, Can anyone help? My tick() is being called by my thread every second in case you were wondering.

Comment: `"Every time it comes out as 0, Can anyone help?"` -- What do you mean "every time". It's only called once in your code. Please show real code that you use to test it.

Comment: what is calling tick()?

Comment: I don't see where you are changing it.

Comment: No need to add tags in question title. SO have tag system already. Take a look at [this topic](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you are calling `tick()` in another thread, you have entered the dark world of concurrency and thread safety.

Put simply, changes made in one thread are not necessarily visible to other threads, unless you follow some strict rules:

- make the field `volatile`
- all access to it must be synchronized

Ergo:

```
private volatile int timer = 0;

public synchronized void tick(){
    if(updateVar == true) timer++;
}

pubic synchronized int getTimer(){
    return timer;
}
```

You may also have to `join()` the updating thread to wait for it to complete if you are not in a wait loop in the main thread.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `tick()` if you want the member variable incremented.

Comment: I am it is being called by my thread I did not show it because of it would be a little unnecessary sorry for that

Comment: @NGSoftware: unnecessary? Seriously? It's key. If you don't show it, we cannot help.

Comment: @NGSoftware if you are going to use same variable in few threads it should be declared as `volatile` to prevent its caching by each tread.